# Access IntelliJ UI Components in Platform SDK

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, platform-sdk

I am developing an IntelliJ Plugin with the Platform SDK.

I need to access the UI Swing Elements of the IDE to get their screen location.

I know who to do this for the File Editor:

```
FileEditor currentEditor = FileEditorManager.getInstance(currentProject).getSelectedEditor();
JComponent entryPoint = currentEditor.getComponent();
Point p = entryPoint.getLocationOnScreen();
```

But how can I get access to other UI Components like the Menu Bar or the Project Window? Is there any parent object that holds all the UI Elements?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/bashor/IdeaMainMenuToggler/blob/master/src/com/bashorov/mainMenuToggler/ToggleMainMenuAction.kt) will help.

Comment: The parent component for all UI is `IdeFrame`. The API to access each UI element depends on the element.